# How to set up element in multichannel matrix via CV_MAT_ELEM?

Tags: opencv, matrix, computer-vision

I created [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) matrix:

```
CvMat * src = cvCreateMat(1, 2, CV_32FC2);
```

Then I want to set up element row=0, col=1, channel=1
According to the example in description of [documentation for CvMat](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html?highlight=cvmat#CvMat)
I tried to set element with the following code:

```
 CV_MAT_ELEM(*src, float, 0, 1 * 2 + 1) = 123;
```

But `assert` is fired.
And the reason is obvious:

We have following defintions in OpenCV sources:

```
#define CV_MAT_ELEM_PTR_FAST( mat, row, col, pix_size )  \
    (assert( (unsigned)(row) < (unsigned)(mat).rows &&   \
             (unsigned)(col) < (unsigned)(mat).cols ),   \
    (mat).data.ptr + (size_t)(mat).step*(row) + (pix_size)*(col))

#define CV_MAT_ELEM( mat, elemtype, row, col )           \
    (*(elemtype*)CV_MAT_ELEM_PTR_FAST( mat, row, col, sizeof(elemtype)))
```

In my case `mat.cols == 2` and `col == 1 * 2 + 1 == 3`.

What is wrong: documentation or assert in sources of OpenCV?
How to manage this?
How can I set up element of multichannel matrix?
Thanks.

P.S. To OpenCV developers if anyone here.
When I press "you can create one now" to create new account to report a bug from the page http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Welcome?action=login, I obtain the error "Unknown action newaccount."

**UPDATE:**

I use OpenCV 2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked around usage of `CV_MAT_ELEM`:

```
float * src_ptr = (float*)src->data.ptr;
*(src_ptr + 1 * 2 + 1) = 123;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question, but a good suggestion:
Neither the documentation, nor the source code are wrong.

But why don't you use the C++ interface? I can bet you do not use the C interface because you really need it (you build for some strange embedded platform, that can't compile c++).

```
Mat src(1, 2, CV_32FC2);

// isn't it nicer than CV_UGLY_AND_SCARY_MACRO()?    
src.at<Vec2f>(0,1)[1] = 123; // (0,1) means row 0, col 1. [1] means channel 1.
```

**EDIT**

From OpenCV:

For **single-channel** matrices there is a macro CV_MAT_ELEM( matrix, elemtype, row, col ), i.e. for 32-bit floating point real matrix

Comment: The plantform is Windows - no problem with it. But EmguCV internally uses C interface and I investigate behavior of it. Could you please clarify why doc and sources are consistent? You just stated without pointing out the reason. Thanks.

Comment: It's always good to recheck. I knew that the macro works, but OpenCV docs shed some more light into the problem - single channel only! See the edit above

Comment: The doc says how to use multichannel here http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html?highlight=cvmat#CvMat - see note for multichannel, when you say "single channel only", you contradict with documentation! - there is no so limitation in doc. But example from the link to doc does not work. I don't undestand what is wrong with my code.

Comment: What version of OpenCV are you using? I have cited an older documentation page, maybe the one matching your version. In a newer version, they may allow multichannel, as the new doc says. Check it here http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/faq

Comment: I use OpenCV 2.1, but just rechecked sources of 2.3 - the same assert. I also use OpenCV doc, but not faq. You may find link in my question. Anyway thanks for support. Just will keep in mind for future that OpenCV documention is not accurate enough.

Comment: @sergdev I am also trying to access the elements of a multi-channel matrix. I saw from your above lonk, that CV_MAT_ELEM(matrix, type, i, j*nchannels + channel_idx) is used for doing this. Did you try this to see if it worked?

Comment: @sue-ling You may take a look to my answer accepted - I have used approach without CV_MAT_ELEM

Comment: @sue-ling when you have several channels, you should substitute col_index <- col_index * num_channels + channel_index in my answer. I didn't tried it, but investigated related features later, seems should work.